# How would I return a paragraph value into HTML in a tic tac toe game?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm currently trying to learn JS in the browser for one of my college classes. I pretty much have everything functional except for one major thing. I can't get the program to actually register the victory message when the player or PC wins, and after a solution is found it becomes the player's turn infinitely. I tried moving things around in my code and I was able to find a way to bypass this, but it also caused tie games to crash the page because the computer would run calculations forever. Would there be a way to get the victory message without the page crashing?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <title>Tic-Tac-Toe</title>
   <style>
      td {
         border: 1px solid lightblue;
         padding: 10px;
         font-size: 64pt;
         font-family: Courier;
         width: 100px;
         height: 100px;
         text-align: center;
      }
   </style>
   <script src="tictactoe.js"></script>

   <body>
      <h1>Tic-Tac-Toe</h1>

      <!-- 3x3 table for the game board -->
      <table id="gameBoard">
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <p id="turnInfo">TURN INFO</p>
      <input id="newGameButton" type="button" value="New game">
   </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
let playerTurn = true;
let computerMoveTimeout = 0;

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", domLoaded);

function domLoaded() {
    // Setup the click event for the "New game" button
    let newBtn = document.getElementById("newGameButton");
    newBtn.addEventListener("click", newGame);

    // Create click-event listeners for each cell in the game board
    let cells = getGameBoard();
    for (let cell of cells) {
        cell.addEventListener("click", function () { cellClicked(cell); });
    }

    // Call newGame() to make sure the board is clear
    newGame();
}

// Returns an array of 9 <td> elements that make up the game board. The first 3 
// elements are the top row, the next 3 the middle row, and the last 3 the 
// bottom row. 
function getGameBoard() {
    let gameBoardTable = document.getElementById("gameBoard");
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            result.push(gameBoardTable.rows[i].cells[j]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

function newGame() {
    let paragraph = document.getElementById("turnInfo");
    let cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    
    clearTimeout(computerMoveTimeout);
    computerMoveTimeout = 0;
    
    for(i=0; i<cells.length; i++) {
        cells[i].innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
    }
    
    playerTurn = true;
    paragraph.innerHTML = "Your turn";
    
}

function cellClicked(cell) {
    if(playerTurn && cell.innerHTML == "&nbsp;") {
        cell.innerHTML = "X";
        cell.style.color = "red";
        
        switchTurn();
    }
}

function switchTurn() {
    let paragraph = document.getElementById("turnInfo");
    let selector = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    let counter = 0;
    
    winningRows("X", 0, 1, 2);
    winningRows("X", 0, 3, 6);
    winningRows("X", 0, 4, 8);
    winningRows("X", 1, 4, 7);
    winningRows("X", 2, 5, 8);
    winningRows("X", 2, 4, 6);
    winningRows("X", 3, 4, 5);
    winningRows("X", 6, 7, 8);
    
    winningRows("O", 0, 1, 2);
    winningRows("O", 0, 3, 6);
    winningRows("O", 0, 4, 8);
    winningRows("O", 1, 4, 7);
    winningRows("O", 2, 5, 8);
    winningRows("O", 2, 4, 6);
    winningRows("O", 3, 4, 5);
    winningRows("O", 6, 7, 8);
    
    for(i=0; i<selector.length; i++) {
        if(selector[i].innerHTML == "X" || selector[i].innerHTML == "O") {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    
    if(counter > 8) {
        paragraph.innerHTML = "TIE!";
        playerTurn = false;
        return;
    }
    
    else {
        if(playerTurn) {
            paragraph.innerHTML = "Computer's turn";
            playerTurn = false;
            computerMoveTimeout = setTimeout(makeComputerMove, 1000);
        }
        else {
            paragraph.innerHTML = "Your turn";
            playerTurn = true;
        }
    }
    
}

function winningRows(letter, num1, num2, num3) {
    let selector = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    let paragraph = document.getElementById("turnInfo");
    
    if(letter == "X" && selector[num1].innerHTML == letter) {
        if(selector[num1].innerHTML == selector[num2].innerHTML && selector[num2].innerHTML == selector[num3].innerHTML) {
            paragraph.innerHTML = "You win!";
            playerTurn = false;
            return;
        }
    }
    if(letter == "O" && selector[num1].innerHTML == letter) {
        if(selector[num1].innerHTML == selector[num2].innerHTML && selector[num2].innerHTML == selector[num3].innerHTML) {
            paragraph.innerHTML = "Computer wins!";
            playerTurn = false;
            return;
        }
    }
}

function makeComputerMove() {
    let selector = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    let paragraph = document.getElementById("turnInfo");
    let freespot;
    let found = false;
    
    while(found == false) {
        freespot = Math.floor(Math.random() * selector.length);
        
        console.log(freespot);
        if(selector[freespot].innerHTML != "X" && selector[freespot].innerHTML != "O") {
            selector[freespot].innerHTML = "O";
            selector[freespot].style.color = "blue";
            found = true;
        }
    }
    
    switchTurn();
}
```

Comment: When the winningRows method finds a win it should mark it. You could set a boolean var to true when that happens. After it does so, the switchTurn method should detect this and emediately return. Right now, since playerTurn is set to false, the computer will always get the turn and if the board happens to be fully filled the while loop inside MakeComputerMove will run infinetely causing the crash.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let playerTurn = true;
let gameFinished = false;
let computerMoveTimeout = 0;

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", domLoaded);

function domLoaded() {
    // Setup the click event for the "New game" button
    let newBtn = document.getElementById("newGameButton");
    newBtn.addEventListener("click", newGame);

    // Create click-event listeners for each cell in the game board
    let cells = getGameBoard();
    for (let cell of cells) {
        cell.addEventListener("click", function () { cellClicked(cell); });
    }

    // Call newGame() to make sure the board is clear
    newGame();
}

// Returns an array of 9 <td> elements that make up the game board. The first 3 
// elements are the top row, the next 3 the middle row, and the last 3 the 
// bottom row. 
function getGameBoard() {
    let gameBoardTable = document.getElementById("gameBoard");
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            result.push(gameBoardTable.rows[i].cells[j]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

function newGame() {
    gameFinished = false;
    let paragraph = document.getElementById("turnInfo");
    let cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    
    clearTimeout(computerMoveTimeout);
    computerMoveTimeout = 0;
    
    for(i=0; i<cells.length; i++) {
        cells[i].innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
    }
    
    playerTurn = true;
    paragraph.innerHTML = "Your turn";
    
}

function cellClicked(cell) {
    if(playerTurn && cell.innerHTML == "&nbsp;") {
        cell.innerHTML = "X";
        cell.style.color = "red";
        
        switchTurn();
    }
}

function switchTurn() {
    let paragraph = document.getElementById("turnInfo");
    let selector = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    let counter = 0;
    
    winningRows("X", 0, 1, 2);
    winningRows("X", 0, 3, 6);
    winningRows("X", 0, 4, 8);
    winningRows("X", 1, 4, 7);
    winningRows("X", 2, 5, 8);
    winningRows("X", 2, 4, 6);
    winningRows("X", 3, 4, 5);
    winningRows("X", 6, 7, 8);
    
    winningRows("O", 0, 1, 2);
    winningRows("O", 0, 3, 6);
    winningRows("O", 0, 4, 8);
    winningRows("O", 1, 4, 7);
    winningRows("O", 2, 5, 8);
    winningRows("O", 2, 4, 6);
    winningRows("O", 3, 4, 5);
    winningRows("O", 6, 7, 8);
    
    if (gameFinished) {
       return;
    }
    
    for(i=0; i<selector.length; i++) {
        if(selector[i].innerHTML == "X" || selector[i].innerHTML == "O") {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    
    if(counter > 8) {
        paragraph.innerHTML = "TIE!";
        playerTurn = false;
        return;
    }
    
    else {
        if(playerTurn) {
            paragraph.innerHTML = "Computer's turn";
            playerTurn = false;
            computerMoveTimeout = setTimeout(makeComputerMove, 1000);
        }
        else {
            paragraph.innerHTML = "Your turn";
            playerTurn = true;
        }
    }
    
}

function winningRows(letter, num1, num2, num3) {
    let selector = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    let paragraph = document.getElementById("turnInfo");
    
    if(letter == "X" && selector[num1].innerHTML == letter) {
        if(selector[num1].innerHTML == selector[num2].innerHTML && selector[num2].innerHTML == selector[num3].innerHTML) {
            paragraph.innerHTML = "You win!";
            playerTurn = false;
            gameFinished = true;
            return;
        }
    }
    if(letter == "O" && selector[num1].innerHTML == letter) {
        if(selector[num1].innerHTML == selector[num2].innerHTML && selector[num2].innerHTML == selector[num3].innerHTML) {
            paragraph.innerHTML = "Computer wins!";
            playerTurn = false;
            gameFinished = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}

function makeComputerMove() {
    let selector = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    let paragraph = document.getElementById("turnInfo");
    let freespot;
    let found = false;
    
    while(found == false) {
        freespot = Math.floor(Math.random() * selector.length);
        
        console.log(freespot);
        if(selector[freespot].innerHTML != "X" && selector[freespot].innerHTML != "O") {
            selector[freespot].innerHTML = "O";
            selector[freespot].style.color = "blue";
            found = true;
        }
    }
    
    switchTurn();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <title>Tic-Tac-Toe</title>
   <style>
      td {
         border: 1px solid lightblue;
         padding: 10px;
         font-size: 64pt;
         font-family: Courier;
         width: 100px;
         height: 100px;
         text-align: center;
      }
   </style>
   <script src="tictactoe.js"></script>

   <body>
      <h1>Tic-Tac-Toe</h1>

      <!-- 3x3 table for the game board -->
      <table id="gameBoard">
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <p id="turnInfo">TURN INFO</p>
      <input id="newGameButton" type="button" value="New game">
   </body>
</html>
```